# Send XML data to C# Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, xml

I want to send xml data to c# controller.

my xml data is:

```
var saveData = '<xml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><block type="animal" id="xG;UTYXlRg!0Mf[hzwUY" deletable="false" x="601" y="32"><mutation animal="4"></mutation><field name="LEGS">4</field><value name="PIC"><block type="picture" id="Ur(^~L/jC/yu!u%f%I(Z" deletable="false"><mutation animal="4"></mutation></block></value><statement name="TRAITS"><block type="trait" id="u8)T)6wBbE^m.%=ILpEe" deletable="false"><mutation animal="4" trait="1"></mutation><next><block type="trait" id="H@d0NIKR1u0@@(t?7a6Dw" deletable="false"><mutation animal="4" trait="2"></mutation></block></next></block></statement></block><block type="animal" id="d@Q?[m;zlWRWA,5X5M/a" deletable="false" x="891" y="36"><mutation animal="1"></mutation><field name="LEGS">1</field><value name="PIC"><block type="picture" id="w!UiV*|:=y5n8`f@M!3j" deletable="false"><mutation animal="1"></mutation></block></value><statement name="TRAITS"><block type="trait" id="zQp:H!fm::@@aNFn`4eEd" deletable="false"><mutation animal="1" trait="1"></mutation><next><block type="trait" id="4wDt7k=~:}J[un#^rhal" deletable="false"><mutation animal="1" trait="2"></mutation></block></next></block></statement></block><block type="animal" id="i8kBocDwY3|Q5oy}#K/0" deletable="false" x="595" y="244"><mutation animal="2"></mutation><field name="LEGS">2</field><value name="PIC"><block type="picture" id="v6/SG@D#WfS*kGU?h4H@@" deletable="false"><mutation animal="2"></mutation></block></value><statement name="TRAITS"><block type="trait" id="C^+-{YCH;}19X6TuW=NW" deletable="false"><mutation animal="2" trait="2"></mutation><next><block type="trait" id="zuTZ?E^YtPgLV8Otz!W=" deletable="false"><mutation animal="2" trait="1"></mutation></block></next></block></statement></block><block type="animal" id="P)KN^:PPLG0*DYS==b_i" deletable="false" x="913" y="270"><mutation animal="3"></mutation><field name="LEGS">3</field><value name="PIC"><block type="picture" id="~kZ?pV,{zka*L6p^*K*j" deletable="false"><mutation animal="3"></mutation></block></value><statement name="TRAITS"><block type="trait" id="nLR]),jTS*m-.8*7(p|a" deletable="false"><mutation animal="3" trait="2"></mutation><next><block type="trait" id="*UtIP}fT=7@b19ssf{72" deletable="false"><mutation animal="3" trait="1"></mutation></block></next></block></statement></block></xml>'
```

and I am sending it like this

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../Home/XmlData",
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "text/xml",
         dataType: "xml",
         async: false,
         data: { "SaveData": saveData },
         success: function (result) {

         },
         error: function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {

         }
     })
```

but I got `null` in controller.

kindly help me out

Comment: data is not posted here..... lets say its a simple xml data

Comment: 1) XML is not JSON.   2) Show your controller

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult XmlData(string SaveData)
        {
            return Json('1', JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: i have tried this too

contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",

Comment: ContentType should be `application/json`.  your controller is expecting a string, but you're passing an object with a "SaveData" Property instead.

Comment: savedata is a variable containing xml 
like var savedata = <xml><note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note></xml>

Comment: by doing contenttype to json got InternalServerError

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have got the answer.

By doing this, it will post the XML.

```
processData: false,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: JSON.stringify({ SaveData: saveData })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're actually posting a *string*, not XML.
Maybe try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Home/XmlData",
    data: saveData, 
    contentType: 'text/plain'
});
```

you will then need to parse the XML at the controller end of course, and I think your controller should probably look like this:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult XmlData([FromBody]string SaveData) 
{ 
    //...Do whatever is needed.
}
```

As otherwise it'll expect the 'saveData' string to be part of the url.

Comment: what if [FromBody] is?

Comment: It's informing the routing part of MVC that the 'SaveData' variable is from the POST BODY, and not part of the url/querystring/etc.